# How stop Repeat when first results are found in Gremlin TinkerPop Graph

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

How can I stop traversing further down a graph using a Repeat when the first results are found?
I have tried to use an aggregate variable but it seem that the until step ignores it.

Se demo
https://gremlify.com/2gr4460avv1

I cannot get the this line to work in the until step:

```
sack().is(within('level'))
```

eg. with the following graph:

```
g.addV('User 0').as('0').
  property(single, 'name', 'v0').
  addV('User 1').as('1').
  property(single, 'name', 'v1').
  addV('User 2').as('2').
  property(single, 'name', 'v2').
  addV('User 3').as('3').
  property(single, 'name', 'v3').
  addV('User 4').as('4').
  property(single, 'name', 'v3').
  addV('Subject 1').as('5').
  property(single, 'name', 's1').
  addE('Trust').from('0').to('1').property("distance", 1).
  addE('Trust').from('0').to('2').property("distance", 1).
  addE('Trust').from('0').to('3').property("distance", 1).
  addE('Trust').from('1').to('2').property("distance", 1).
  addE('Trust').from('1').to('4').property("distance", 1).
  addE('Audit').from('2').to('5').property("distance", 0).
  addE('Trust').from('2').to('3').property("distance", 1).
  addE('Audit').from('3').to('5').property("distance", 0).
  addE('Trust').from('3').to('0').property("distance", 1).
  addE('Audit').from('4').to('2').property("distance", 0)
```

Query:

```
g.withSack(0).V().has("name", "v0").
    repeat(outE("Trust", "Audit").as("e").sack(sum).by('distance').
        inV().simplePath().
        choose(
            select("e").hasLabel("Trust"),
            choose(
                select("e").has("distance", gte(0)),
                    aggregate('allow'),
                    aggregate('distrust')
            )
        )
    ).
    until( 
        has('name', 's1').
        or().
        sack().is(gte(3)).
        or().
        sack().is(within('level')).
        or().
        where(within('distrust'))
        
    ).
    has('name', 's1').
    sack(sum).by(constant(1)).sack().aggregate('level').
    path()
```

Result:

```
==>[v[0],e[13][0-Trust->4],v[4],e[17][4-Audit->10],v[10],2]
==>[v[0],e[14][0-Trust->6],v[6],e[19][6-Audit->10],v[10],2]
==>[v[0],e[12][0-Trust->2],v[2],e[16][2-Trust->8],v[8],e[21][8-Audit->10],v[10],3]
==>[v[0],e[12][0-Trust->2],v[2],e[15][2-Trust->4],v[4],e[17][4-Audit->10],v[10],3]
==>[v[0],e[13][0-Trust->4],v[4],e[18][4-Trust->6],v[6],e[19][6-Audit->10],v[10],3]
```

But I want the gremlin to stop at the level of the first result. e.g. so the result should look like this.

```
==>[v[0],e[13][0-Trust->4],v[4],e[17][4-Audit->10],v[10],2]
==>[v[0],e[14][0-Trust->6],v[6],e[19][6-Audit->10],v[10],2]
```

The query should find one or more result at the same degree if they exist, then stop looking for longer routes.

The idea is that in a very large graph the query stops early if it finds one or more results at the same degree.

PS! withComputer() would be nice, but I need to filter untrusted user away from the route calculation dynamically and cannot see how this can be done using the shortestPath() function.

Comment: Just a quick comment. As time allows I will try to write up a full answer - unless someone else beats me to it :-)  For these cases where you are essentially wanting to loop while a value is within some range you may need `and` logic rather than `or`. Also note that as written `within('level')` will treat 'level' as a literal string. You are going to need something like `where(within('level')).by(sack())`

Answer (score 0):

I did not yet have time to try with your data set, but here is an example that uses a data set I had to hand that shows how to end a `repeat` based on the `sack` value having exceeded a given threshold.

```java
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('level',3000).
......1>   withSack(0).
......2>   V(44).
......3>   repeat(outE().sack(sum).by('dist').inV().simplePath()).
......4>   until(where(gt('level')).by(sack()).by().or().loops().is(3)).
......5>   path().
......6>     by('code').
......7>     by('dist').
......8>   limit(3) 

==>[SAF,549,DFW,4736,LHR]
==>[SAF,549,DFW,4933,CDG]
==>[SAF,549,DFW,5127,FRA]
```

I added the `loops` test just to avoid any runaway queries, but it is not needed if the dataset is well understood to not have that potential.

```java
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('level',3000).
......1>   withSack(0).
......2>   V(44).
......3>   repeat(outE().sack(sum).by('dist').inV().simplePath()).
......4>   until(where(gt('level')).by(sack()).by()).
......5>   path().
......6>     by('code').
......7>     by('dist').
......8>   limit(3) 

==>[SAF,549,DFW,4736,LHR]
==>[SAF,549,DFW,4933,CDG]
==>[SAF,549,DFW,5127,FRA]
```

The key takeaway here is that `where(predicate('string'))` is a special case of `where` such that the string is treated as the name of a "variable" and not a literal string, as in `where(within('my-list'))`.

Note also that if all you really want is a depth counter, you can just use `loops` and not worry about managing a `sack`.

Here is one last example, that adds an `and` step to the `until`. This will stop when distances greater than 3000 are found AND those distances are between 3001 and 4500 miles, or `loops` gets to 3.

```java
gremlin> g.withSideEffect('level',3000).
......1>   withSack(0).
......2>   V(44).
......3>   repeat(outE().sack(sum).by('dist').inV().simplePath()).
......4>   until(and((where(gt('level')).by(sack()).by()),
......5>             sack().is(between(3001,4500))).
......6>         or().loops().is(3)).
......7>   path().
......8>     by('code').
......9>     by('dist').
.....10>   limit(3)    

==>[SAF,549,DFW,3368,LIM]
==>[SAF,549,DFW,3702,OGG]
==>[SAF,549,DFW,3733,KEF]
```